# Bokeh Hover Tool, tooltips argument: issues with date and time format

Tags: python, python-2.7, bokeh

I have some issues with the hover tool. [The documentition about tooltips argument](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.1/docs/user_guide/tools.html#basic-tooltips) is a bit short for beginners. I need more detail about how to use `@` and `$` in `tooltips` argument while referring to data source as I am not able to show properly what I need. Furthermore, an example would be apreciated of how to show an index based in timestamp in the hover tool. The data source is a Pandas data frame. Last thing I tried was this:

```
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
csv_file = 'CSV_Session_2017-01-26_14.47.22.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, header=0, sep=';', parse_dates={'datetime':  ['Date', 'Time']}, date_parser=dateparse)

datetime = df['datetime'].tolist()
datetime = map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'), datetime)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(date=datetime))
hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips=[
        ('Date', '$datetime'),
    ]
)

df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
```

I know that in the example above i am not working with the index but a column. I was trying different possibilities as I guess a problem with the format was probably also happening.

Comment: Have you tried my answer?